# Filtering by UserGroups in LDAP

Tags: regex, ldap, wso2-identity-server

I've a requirement that i need to filter UserGroups (single or multiple) using regex expression. I have been working on this for last 3hrs, and I'm no where near of resolving it.


what is the most efficient way of filtering UserGroups in LDAP using regex. 
This is my current pattern.

In my current setup I've UserGroups/Roles with following names

- Admin
- Internal/system
- Application/everyone

I want to get the UserGroups that's only starting with **Internal/*** and **Admin**. Any advice on this highly appreciated.

Current Group Search Filter - `(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))`

`cn` - Group Name Attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT use regex within an LDAP Filter.

```
(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(|(cn=Internal*)(cn=Admin*))
```

Should get you close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you @jwilleke I will try this out, i have been pulling out my hair on this one.